# How to get index of removed element in the sub array

Tags: javascript

I have an array `all = [2,3,4,12, 55,33]` and `ar1 = [12, 55, 33]` which is a sub array of `all` (starts from 12).

When I remove a value from `all` which is a part of `ar1`(ex:12) how do I get the index of that value in `ar1`(for 12 it is 0) so that I can remove it from `ar1` also.

**Edit:** I actually have objects in my array. I used numbers here as example

Comment: [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) : `all.indexOf(...)`

Comment: @Zenoo will it work if it there are objects in array too?

Comment: that requires each item to be unique

Comment: suggests you use objects in which you will add an index. For example, {value:1, id:1}, and so on

Comment: As long as the arrays refer to the same object - indexOf will find it (compares reference).

Comment: @Daniel thanks Daniel.. i guess i will have to use `indexOf` then. i didn't know it works on objects

Answer (score 3):

Since you specified that your array contains objects, you should give each object an individual `id`, so that you can use the `id` to filter it. Your objects, apart from the `id`, can hold any other data.

You can then use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the corresponding object.

Example:

```
const arr = [{ id: "abc" }, { id: "def" }];
arr.findIndex (itm => itm.id === "def") // Returns 1
```

Alternatively, in case you cannot add an `id`, you will have do do a deep object comparison (which is not 100% accurate, but works in most cases). You could either use a standalone implementation, or, for example, Lodash's [`_.isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual).

Comment: thanks, i thought about using an id too, but this was not written by me and i cant change the code to add an id

Comment: Are there any other identifying elements in the object?

Comment: You will have to do a deep comparison then, I guess. I've edited my post. If there are no other identifying items, how can you be sure that an object is unique throughout your array?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use [**Array#splice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to remove the element from the first array, then check for its `index` using [**Array#findIndex()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then remove it from the second `array`.

```
var [removed] = all.splice(3, 1);
var index = ar1.findIndex(el => el.val == removed.val);
if (index !== -1) {
  ar1.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var all = [{ val: 2}, { val: 3}, {val: 4}, {val: 12}, {val: 55
  }, {val: 33}],
  ar1 = [{val: 12}, {val: 55}, {val: 33}];

var [removed] = all.splice(3, 1);
console.log(removed);

var index = ar1.findIndex(el => el.val == removed.val);

if (index !== -1) {
  ar1.splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(ar1);
```

Comment: @boo yes but you can always use any other identifiers you judge relevant.